# Como definir valor em um formBuilder.array em Angular?

Tags: angular, formulário

Eu usando formulários relativos no angular 4, estou com problema ao definir um valor para o array. Como definir seu valor ?

```
marketStructures: this.formBuilder.group({
 include: this.formBuilder.group({
  departments: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
 })
})

createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      code: '',
    });
  }


this.formulario.patchValue({
      'departments': { code: '01' }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ele ser um array vc tem que setar o array interio ou pra setar um valor só usar o metodo at

```
this.formulario.patchValue({
      'departments': [{ code: '01' }]
    })
```

ou então

```
this.formulario.get('departments').at(0).patchValue({ code: '01' })
```